# PayPal express checkout requiring users to login twice

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I have an issue with PayPal Express Checkout requiring users to log in twice.  Screens are in Italian, but they should look familiar.  How can this be avoided?  Thanks.  Images show the two pages: [This page comes up first.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wnsl.jpg)  Then, user logs in and then [this page comes up next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApgUc.jpg).
How can I avoid this?  Thanks!
-jpr

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache / cookies.  If it continues after that I would post it directly to [PayPal MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts).

Comment: No joy.  Also, we've had this open with PayPal support for 6 months now and it is currently "pending fix", yet they have given us no feedback about what the issue is or how to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, this was happening because the third party product we were using was putting the whole country name in instead of a short ISO code.  Not sure why that caused this behavior, but fixing that problem resolved this.

Comment: Actually, this just changed the behavior to prompt for credit card information twice.  This issue is still open.